# Кроссплатформенность битовых операций

Tags: c++, битовые-операции, кроссплатформенность

Как добиться кроссплатформенности при сериализации, работе напрямую с битами, составления пакетов для отправки между классами при условии, что битовые манипуляции должны быть верны при `little endian` и `big endian`.

Comment: Интересно что такое "отправка пакетов между классами", классы как бы структурами в памяти оперируют, а пакеты в сети ходят. по хорошему надо просто для каждого базового типа размером больше 1 байта сделать функцию перестановки байт. на одной платформе она возвращает само число, на другой переставляет байты

Comment: Думаю термин "пакеты между классами" связан с общением между потоками процесса, а так же общением между процессами. Возможно формулировка про пакеты не однозначная, за что извиняюсь, но в вопросе подключение к сети не затрагивается. Но проблема ясна: код битовых операций на разных архитектурах

Comment: @rikimaru2013 при общении в пределах одной системы учитывать порядок байт нет смысла. все потоки, процессы и т.п. работают с одним порядком. вопрос собственно встает только при передаче информации на другую платформу

Comment: @Mike Спасибо не знал. Проблемы появятся получаются, когда надо подружить приложение с другим (по сети или еще как).

Comment: @Mike перепишите эту цитату "при общении в пределах одной системы учитывать порядок байт нет смысла. все потоки, процессы и т.п. работают с одним порядком. вопрос собственно встает только при передаче информации на другую платформу" как ответ на данный вопрос - отмечу соотвественно.

Comment: @rikimaru2013, так ведь смысл кроссплатформенности распределенного приложения как раз в том и состоит, что разные компоненты могут работать на *разных платформах* (т.е. желательно, чтобы компонент по возможности не был привязан к одной платформе (да, это не всегда нужно, но часто желательно))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При общении в пределах одной системы учитывать порядок байт нет смысла. все потоки, процессы и т.п. работают с одним порядком. Вопрос встает только при передаче информации на другую платформу. Т.е. данные должны быть приведены к заранее оговоренному порядку байт только при передаче по сети или при записи в файлы, которые могут быть впоследствии перенесены на другую систему.

Answer (score 1):

В полях структур, используемых для обмена, храните данные в сетевом формате (network order, подробнее можете посмотреть [здесь](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)).

Для преобразования данных между сетевым форматом и форматом хоста можно использовать функции `htons()/htonl()/ntohs()/ntohl()` из Berkeley sockets API.

Comment: @Abyx, наверное по привычке. Когда-то (еще во времена, когда только ваяли RPC и NFS) люди неявно (или может явно, уже не помню) договорились об этом (кстати, тогда именно big endian (VAX, pdp) был более распространенным у разработчиков)

Comment: Все же перепутал. VAX и PDP были little-endian, а MC68xxx big-endian. В любом случае [the historic RFC 1700 (also known as Internet standard STD 2) has defined the network order for protocols in the Internet protocol suite to be big-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Networking)

Comment: @Abyx, кстати, Java big-endian (а это куча прог в андроиде), так что вопрос о распространенности формата явно остается открытым.

Answer (score 1):

Внутри байта биты всегда идут слева направо от старшего к младшему, независимо от принятого порядка байтов в системе. То же самое касается операндов у операторов `>> <<`, даже если это числа, состоящие из больше чем 1-го байта. То есть `int i=4; i>>=1;` i всегда будет равно 2.

Для кроссплатформенной (де)сериализации можно использовать htons()/htonl()/ntohs()/ntohl()